# How to have multiple images show randomly in a game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, game-development

Is it possible to fix my code so that there are multiple balls showing up randomly and constantly in the game at the same time? Currently the balls are showing up one at a time every 1.5 seconds. I think I might need to change the interval in the start function possibly.

I'm still new at coding and I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.  Thank you in advance

Here is my code:

```js
// Declaring the images to use
var imagesArray = [
"./green-ball.png",
"./yellow-ball.png",
"./blue-ball.png",
"./light-pink-ball.png",
"./purple-ball.png",
];

// Declaring the starting points
let score = 0;
let timer = 15;
var interval;
let timeLeft = 15;
let lastScore = 0;

// Setting game and images
var img = document.createElement("img")
const images = document.getElementsByClassName(imagesArray);
var game = document.getElementById("game");
const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
const timerElement = document.getElementById("timer");

// Game over function - clearing the info and resetting variables and updating the last score
function gameOver() {
    var lastScoreElement = document.getElementById("lastScore");
    clearInterval(timer);
    clearInterval(interval);
    $("#playAgainButton").show();
    $("#lastScore").show(
        lastScoreElement.textContent = " " + score
    );
    ResetGlobalVariables;
}

// Making the random function
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//Creating the images to show up in random positions
function createImage() {
    img.src = imagesArray[random(0, imagesArray.length - 1)];
    img.width = random(50, 200);
    img.height = random(50, 200);
    img.style.left = random(0, 800 - img.width) + "px";
    img.style.top = random(0, 600 - img.height) + "px";
    img.alt = img.src.split('/').pop(); // to show the colour
    return img;
}

// Creating the updateTimer function - once timer runs out, game is over
function updateTimer() {
    timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
    if(timeLeft >= 0)
        $("#timer").html(timeLeft);
    else {
        gameOver();
    }; 1000;
}

// Creating the start of the game - setting the timer and creating the balls
function start() {
    timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    updateTimer();
    $("#playAgainButton").hide();
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var img = createImage();
        game.appendChild(img);
    }, 1500);
}

// Function to reset the global variables - clean slate
function ResetGlobalVariables() {
    score = 0;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = "Current Score: " + score;
    timer = 15;
    timerElement.innerHTML = timer;
    timeLeft = 15;
}

// Update when the reset button is clicked
const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset-button")
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", ResetGlobalVariables)

// Add event listener - if the ball is green update the score, if the ball is any other colour    lose a point
game.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches('img')) return; // not a ball
    if (!tgt.src.includes('green'))score--; // not green
    else
        score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = "Current Score: " + score;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Find Greenie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="find.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="game"></div>
                </td>
                <td id="text">
                    <p id="gameTitle">Find Greenie!<img src="green-ball.png" alt="Logo"></p>
                    <p id="score">Current Score: 0</p>
                    <p> You have: <span id="timer">15</span> seconds remaining!</p>
                    <button id="playAgainButton" onclick="start()">Go!</button>
                    <input id="reset" type="button" class="reset-button" value="Reset">
                    <p> You scored: <span id="lastScore"></span></p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p>Click on Greenie the green ball to score points</p>
                    <p>But click on any other ball and lose a point!</p>
                    <p>Click Reset and then Go! to restart</p>
                    <script src="find.js"></script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Random intervals

To have the balls drawn at random intervals, consider using a function that calls itself after a period of random time, instead of `setInterval()`. `setInterval()` will always call the given function at the same interval.

```js
function start() {
  timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
  updateTimer();
  $("#playAgainButton").hide();
  drawBalls();
}

function drawBalls() {
  // If the game is running:
  if (timeLeft >= 0) {
    // Draw a ball.
    var img = createImage();
    game.appendChild(img);
    // Wait for a time between 0–1500ms before drawing another ball.
    setTimeout(drawBalls, random(0, 1500));
  }
}
```

### Multiple balls

For having multiple balls available at any one time, do not have a single reference to the `img` variable. This causes a single `<img>` to be updated, instead of new ones. This means only one `<img>` can exist at any one time. Instead, have an `<img>` element be created in every call to `createImage()`:

```js
function createImage() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  // …
}
```

Presumably, you'd want the images to disappear at some point. We can remove them by calling its [`remove()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove):

```js
function createImage() {
  // …
  setTimeout(() => img.remove(), random(1000, 2000));
  // …
}
```

### Working example

```js
// Declaring the images to use
var imagesArray = [
  "https://placehold.co/200x200/forestgreen/white",
  "https://placehold.co/200x200/gold/black",
  "https://placehold.co/200x200/mediumblue/white",
  "https://placehold.co/200x200/hotpink/white",
  "https://placehold.co/200x200/darkorchid/white",
];

// Declaring the starting points
let score = 0;
let timer = 15;
var interval;
let timeLeft = 15;
let lastScore = 0;

// Setting game and images
const images = document.getElementsByClassName(imagesArray);
var game = document.getElementById("game");
const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
const timerElement = document.getElementById("timer");

// Game over function - clearing the info and resetting variables and updating the last score
function gameOver() {
  var lastScoreElement = document.getElementById("lastScore");
  clearInterval(timer);
  clearInterval(interval);
  $("#playAgainButton").show();
  $("#lastScore").show((lastScoreElement.textContent = " " + score));
  ResetGlobalVariables;
}

// Making the random function
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//Creating the images to show up in random positions
function createImage() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imagesArray[random(0, imagesArray.length - 1)];
  img.width = random(50, 200);
  img.height = random(50, 200);
  img.style.left = random(0, 800 - img.width) + "px";
  img.style.top = random(0, 600 - img.height) + "px";
  img.alt = img.src.split("/").pop(); // to show the colour
  setTimeout(() => img.remove(), random(1000, 2000));
  return img;
}

// Creating the updateTimer function - once timer runs out, game is over
function updateTimer() {
  timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
  if (timeLeft >= 0) $("#timer").html(timeLeft);
  else {
    gameOver();
  }
  1000;
}

function drawBalls() {
  if (timeLeft >= 0) {
    var img = createImage();
    game.appendChild(img);
    setTimeout(drawBalls, random(0, 1500));
  }
}

// Creating the start of the game - setting the timer and creating the balls
function start() {
  timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
  updateTimer();
  $("#playAgainButton").hide();
  drawBalls();
}

// Function to reset the global variables - clean slate
function ResetGlobalVariables() {
  score = 0;
  scoreElement.innerHTML = "Current Score: " + score;
  timer = 15;
  timerElement.innerHTML = timer;
  timeLeft = 15;
}

// Update when the reset button is clicked
const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset-button");
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", ResetGlobalVariables);

// Add event listener - if the ball is green update the score, if the ball is any other colour    lose a point
game.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("img")) return; // not a ball
  if (!tgt.src.includes("green")) score--; // not green
  else score++;
  scoreElement.innerHTML = "Current Score: " + score;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Find Greenie</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="find.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="game"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="text">
          <p id="gameTitle">
            Find Greenie!<img src="https://placehold.co/200x200/forestgreen/white" alt="Logo" />
          </p>
          <p id="score">Current Score: 0</p>
          <p>You have: <span id="timer">15</span> seconds remaining!</p>
          <button id="playAgainButton" onclick="start()">Go!</button>
          <input id="reset" type="button" class="reset-button" value="Reset" />
          <p>You scored: <span id="lastScore"></span></p>
          <br />
          <br />
          <p>Click on Greenie the green ball to score points</p>
          <p>But click on any other ball and lose a point!</p>
          <p>Click Reset and then Go! to restart</p>
          <script src="find.js"></script>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```